# In Kant, are "pure intuition" and "intuition a priori" synonyms?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, kant

I'm reading the prolegomena, and in §7, Kant presents both

- "pure intuition" (reine Anschauung), mentioned many times, and
- "intuition a priori" (Anschauung a priori), mentioned twice only.

> it must be grounded in some pure intuition or other, in which it can present, or, as
> one calls it, construct all of its concepts in concreto yet a priori.

> while the latter contains what necessarily must be met with in pure intuition,
> since it is, as intuition a priori, inseparably bound with the concept before
> all experience

The text seems to imply that all pure intuition is a priori, but could there be a intuition that is a priori but is not pure?

Comment: I would say yes. Whatever _pure_ knowledge is precisely such _a priori_ that Kant would be searching (hence the "Pure" in the book's title). Also, I remember listening Dan Robinson on his youtube series about Kant directly associating both terms as synonyms.

Comment: Honestly I didn't have any idea that Kant even uses the term "Anschauung *a priori*". Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- „pure intuition“ = non-empirical intuition, intuition without object
- „intuition a priori“ = intuition which takes place before any
  intuition of an object

I think that Kant uses both terms as synonyms.

In §9 Kant’s emphasizes that the term refers to the **form** of intuition (Form der Sinnlichkeit) not to the **content** of the intuition of concrete objects.

Nevertheless, for me the meaning of this fundamental technical term remains unclear, see also [my former question.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90518/how-is-pure-intuition-possible-according-to-kant?rq=1)

Possibly Kant is influenced by the traditional discrimination between causa materialis and causa formalis. Then pure intuition refers to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

To reinforce the claim, in Paul Guyer's Kant, these are the definitions of a priori and pure in its glossary:

**a priori**: Known or formed independently of particular experience; non-empirical.

**pure (rein)**: Not dependent upon actual experience, although possibly
applicable to it; opposed to empirical.

These look as synonyms to me, and that this conclusion applies not only to intuitions but to all representations.